# Adding data sources for unixODBC/isql on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-lion, unixodbc, isql

I have installed unixODBC from source and [mysql-odbc connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) from .dmg installer on Mac OSX Lion. This was done a while ago, and at that time I successfully installed a data source (let's call it `foo`). Now I am trying to add another data source (DSN). I've done this through both [ODBC Manager](http://www.odbcmanager.net/) and the command-line tool myodbc-installer given with the tar bundle of the mysql-odbc connector from the mysql website. An entry shows up in `/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`, which looks like this:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
bar = MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver

[ODBC]
Trace         = 0
TraceAutoStop = 0
TraceFile     = 
TraceLibrary  = 

[myodbc]
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so
SERVER = localhost
PORT   = 3306

[bar]
Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Description = 
DATABASE    = bar
```

However, isql fails to find it:

```
anitya:Preferences neil$ isql bar bar bar -v
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Weird thing is, the old DSN `foo`, which is not to be seen in /Library/ODBC/odbc.ini or /etc/odbc.ini, works fine:

```
anitya:Preferences neil$ isql foo foo foo
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

I'm miffed about where the DSN entries need to be entered on OSX Lion to be found by isql. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Found it, odbc.ini was in /usr/local/etc